# what is the main factor that an assembly (.exe or .dll) called a shared assembly

Tags: c#

Suppose I make a .dll or .exe assembly and put the same in network shared location and multiple application share the same assembly.

Can we say in abobe case that this is a shared assembly?

And how it is different from Private assembly?

Thanks,

Comment: What is "adobe case"? Are you trying to write a plug-in for an Adobe application?

Comment: no, i am just asking in general....as i know shared assembly must registered with GAC...

Comment: @user584018 - Shared assemblies don't *have to* be in the GAC, though it is typically preferred.

Comment: so in above case can we say the assembly is a shared assembly?

Comment: @user584018 - Your question is too vague and it doesn't sound like you've done your homework on this. It might be beneficial to understand better what you're trying to achieve by using a *shared assembly*.

Comment: go through these links once
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173102.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173102.aspx) [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973231.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973231.aspx)

Comment: @CodyGray "abobe" case seems to be a misspelling of "above" case.

Answer (score 1):

If your just after the technical difference of the two, then this may assist http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/439-What-Assembly-Whats-e-difference-betwee.aspx